# How to achieve set based node selection (using nodeSelector) in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, selector, kubernetes-pod

I have 1 master and 5 nodes cluster.I want to run three nginx pods in two specific nodes.Using nodeSelector i can achieve it but the problem is that all nodes are labled as same key name but different values.

Comment: some one can reply on this?It will be very helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked alpha feature "Node Affinity"? That allows you matching labels in a set. Just search "Alpha feature in Kubernetes v1.2: Node Affinity" in doc http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/. It has an example exactly matching your use case.

Comment: That's supposed to work in 1.2 release. What release are you using? Do you mind sharing your pod spec?